# How can I execute exe file (which writes a txt file) in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, batch-file, cmd, exe, wsh

I want to have a server page which executes a exe file compiled based on C

the exe file is filew.exe generated by filew.c;

filew.c>

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen("test.txt" , "w");
  char* testStr = "this is test string";
  fwrite(testStr , 1 , sizeof(testStr) , fp);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried few methods to accomplish this;

first I tried to run with shellObject

```
Dim shellObj
Set shellObj = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shellObj.run "E:\test\filew.exe"
set shellObj = nothing
```

it didn't work.. so I tried this

```
Dim shellObj 
shellObj = Server.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shellObj.ShellExecute "E:\test\filew.exe"
Set shellObj = nothing
```

Still no... so I made a batch file that executes the exe file

test.bat>

```
dir > e:\test\dir1.txt
E:\test\filew.exe
dir > e:\test\dir2.txt
```

// the first and third line is to test whether the batch file is executed all right or not

I called this batch file by

```
Dim shellObj
Set shellObj = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shellObj.run "E:\test\test.bat"
set shellObj = nothing
```

the result was... only dir1.txt and dir2.txt were created but no test.txt!!

Comment: Have you checked file permissions? The IIS user should be enabled to perform the operation you are describing (executing executables and write files).

Comment: Did you not get any errors/messages?  Try wrapping your code block (ASP) in an `On Error` block.

Comment: .exe files are for executable code, just writing "this is test string" to a file and calling it `something.exe` won't achieve anything as it won't be valid 'machine code' and without the correct header at the start of the file the system will probably ignore it, too.

Comment: You can actually execute an exe via a simple URL if your file/directory permissions allow it, so maybe you could use a zero size iframe.  A lot depends on what your exe actually does

Comment: You're not saying how you executed your tests (on the command prompt?), but in any case, aren't you kinda confirming that what doesn't work is your EXE, and not [asp-classic] or [wscript]? Can you specify how you executed the tests and replace "it didn't work" with the actual output/erro/message or lack of such.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function execStdOut(cmd)
    Dim goWSH : Set goWSH = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) 
    Dim aRet: Set aRet = goWSH.exec(cmd)
    execStdOut = aRet.StdOut.ReadAll()
End Function 

theOutput = execStdOut("c:\runVirus.bat")

response.write "The output is " & theOutput
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot run an EXE from Classic ASP web pages. You will have to create a DLL interface that assumes elevated permissions (more than just a site visitor) to pass the commands to the EXE. Or you can put your code in the DLL and call it like...

```
Set MyDLL = Server.CreateObject("MyDLL.*")
```